# Can I allow specific URL of default Magento2 Frontend and restrict all other Frontend URLs?

Tags: magento2.3, url-rewrite, redirect, redirect-url

Our Magento frontend is in vue storefront, so we have restricted default Magento frontend URLs for our system. But I need one URL of frontend which is

[http://127.0.0.1/index.php/customer/account/createpassword/](https://127.0.0.1/index.php/customer/account/createpassword/)

I allowed it using observer:

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">`
```

and allowed frontname as:

```
if($routname!="customer" ) {

    $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
    $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(),$this->HelperBackend->getHomePageUrl());

}
```

But the problem is after a user set his password he is redirected to this URL:

[http://127.0.0.1/index.php/customer/account/login/](https://127.0.0.1/index.php/customer/account/login/)

I don't want the user to see this URL. Instead, he should be redirected to vue storefront URL or backend URL or any customer url. How can I do this? Thanks

**Update:**

I tried doing like this

```
if ($routname!="customer") {
    if ($controllerName!="account") {
        if ($actionName!="createPassword") {
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(),$this->HelperBackend->getHomePageUrl());
    }
    }
}
```

Still I can access all the actions under frontname "customer". I want only "createPassword" action!

Answer (score 0):

Did it using this condition:

```
If ( !( $route == 'customer' && $controller == 'account' && strtolower($action) == 'createpassword' )) {
//redirect logic here
}
```